# Why are finite groups linearly reductive?

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-groups, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group contained in $GL(n)$. $G$ is linearly reductive iff every regular representation is completely reducible. Among the examples of linearly reductive groups, there are finite groups: why is that?

Comment: What characteristic are you in?

Comment: I am in characteristic zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because for any such group $G$ and its (finite dimensional) representation $V$ we can define on $V$ a hermitian $G$-invariant inner product. Using this product we can easily check that an orthogonal compliment to any $G$-invariant subspace is $G$-invariant itself. Of course everything is in characteristic $c \neq \#G$.

To construct such inner product one can start with an arbitrary hermitian inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ and define
$$
\langle x \, | \, y\rangle = \sum_{g \in G}(gx, gy).
$$

Comment: Where exactly do we use finiteness of $G$ to prove this?

Comment: I made an edit.